# Detect duplicate lines on DB after php filesize()

Tags: php, mysqli, filesize

Having a query that draws multiple lines from a DB, each with an ID, a path and another ID. Is it possible to pass the path by the filesize() function and mark if two or more lines have the same file size?

Here's my code:

```
$q2 = "SELECT idMultimedia, pathURLMult, Type_idType FROM Multimedia";
$e2 = mysqli_query( $conn, $q2 );

while( $r2 = mysqli_fetch_array($e2) ){
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($r2["pathURLMult"]);
    $size = filesize($r2["pathURLMult"]);
    echo $r2["idMultimedia"] . " | " . $r2["pathURLMult"] . " | " . $width. " | " . $height. " | " . $size . "<br>";
}
```

Example of a possible Database output:

```
1  | randomguy1.jpg | 2
2  | A-GUY.jpg      | 3
3  | lol.jpg        | 2
4  | randomguy2.jpg | 1
```

randomguy1.jpg & randomguy2.jpg have the same file size... I need to show that for both pics! How can I do this?

Any help? Thanks in advance!